# Exchange 2007 send as different user by default

Tags: email, exchange, smtp, outlook

Allow me to explain in detail.

I have a client who runs 3 companies under the same roof.  Each user has 3 exchange mailbox accounts (for each company domain) which they load under either Outlook 2007 or 2010.

The company has been using CompanyA.com as the main account with CompanyB.com and CompanyC.com as additional accounts.  They now are now changing their main company to name from CompanyA to CompanyB.

I need help to see if it's possible for the following to be performed:

1. When a user sends an email from ANY of the mailbox accounts from Outlook, OWA, Activesync - the SMTP address is AUTOMATICALLY sent from CompanyB.com (right now it sends as whichever account they send from).
2. If so, can this be configured on a user by user basis and/or configured on a global scale?

Please note that simply forwarding all emails for CompanyA and CompanyC won't be sufficient as they'd like to keep their current inbox rules for the various folders in each mailbox account.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple mailboxes sharing the same email address.  What is your exact setup?  Does Company A, and B and C each have different mailboxes?  or is it a single mailbox per company?  Are you still looking to have three separate entities or do you want to merge them?

Edit 1:

Based on your comment this isn't possible with native exchange / outlook.  Exchange will only allow you to bind one email address to one mailbox.  No exceptions...

The only way to accomplish what you're looking for (in its entirety) is to merge the mailboxes and their email addresses.  Then you'd simply set the primary SMTP address to be the domain that you want.

You can use "send as" rights, but that will only work in Outlook, not EAS, and I'm pretty sure not OWA.

Don't forget, if you send out as one address, that's where its going to return.  So if you send out companya.com from companyb.com, the email will come back to companya.com.  So really, you should just merge the mailboxes.

Comment: There is one user mailbox per Company so thy each have their own SMTP address: ie User Jane Doe has jdoe@companya.com, jdoe@companyb.com, jdoe@companyc.com.  I need to have exchange configure so that it doesn't matter which mailbox use used to send email from Jane Doe, they all appear to be sent as jdoe@companyb.com.

Comment: see my edit above.

Comment: That was my assumption as well but I wanted a 2nd opinion.  Another colleague indicated a transport service or something to that effect could be modified to accomplish but he was not sure and I was unable to find any documentation outlining this.